# .app extension in osx produces a classic application, conflicts with python 2.7 which needs .app

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, python-2.7

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27

The link above requires that the python file be named something like "main.app", but Mac OSX Lion treats such files as "Classic" Mac applications. I have also tried to name the python file "main.application" but still get the same error message in the googleapps log as follows and tells me that their is no module "main".

```
ERROR    2012-05-29 17:10:35,136 wsgi.py:189]   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())  
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])  
ImportError: No module named main  
INFO     2012-05-29 17:10:35,143 dev_appserver.py:2904] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

My app.yaml file is as follows.

```
application: shoppinglist
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: django
  version: "1.3"
- name: PIL
  version: latest
```

What am I doing wrong?

Brian in Atlanta

Answer (score 4):

You don't name the file "main.app"; that's the name of the WSGI application, which is `app` (or, in your case, `application`, with nothing at all named `app`) defined in the file "main.py".

Comment: Yes, that was correct, but now I am getting a similar error "ImportError: No module named webapp2". Is there something else I need to download? I thought webapp2 was part of python 2.7. Thanks.

Comment: webapp2 is not part of python 2.7; it's part of the custom python 2.7 that comes with App Engine SDK 1.6. At any rate, this should be a separate question, not a comment followup here.

Comment: Maybe try removing the webapp2 stanza from app.yaml? As far as I know, it's not required, and including it specifying a version might possibly break something.

Comment: I finally got the app to work by removing the following lines from my main.py #from google.appengine.ext import webapp2
#from google.appengine.ext.webapp2 import template
#from google.appengine.ext.webapp2.util import run_wsgi_app

Comment: You can simply use:  `import webapp2`;  no need to import from google.appengine.ext.  Also, no need for run_wsgi_app.